# run a ruby project on ruby mine

Tags: ruby, rubymine

i am new to ruby programming. i wrote a little program to recursively count blobs in a two dimensional array. it contains two classes, cell and blobs. i am getting the following error and i dont know what it means or how to fix it.

attached is my code and the error.
Cell Class

```
class Cell

  attr_accessor :data,:visited,:row,:col


  def initialize(data, row, col)
      @data = data
      @visited = false
      @row = row
      @col = col
  end

  def to_s
    self.data.to_s
  end

end
```

Blob class

```
class Blobs
 require ./Cell
 @cells = Array.new(10){Array.new(10)}

 def separate(percentage)
   for i in 0..10
     for i in 0..10
       random = Random.rand(0,100)
       if random < percentage
         @cells[i][j] = Cell.new('x',i,j)
       else
         @cells[i][j] = Cell.new(nil, i, j)
       end
     end
   end
 end

 def markBlob(currentCell)
   if currentCell.visited
     return
   end
   currentCell.visited = true
   if currentCell.data.nil?
     return
   end

   if currentCell.row >0
     markBlob(@cells[currentCell.row-1][currentCell.col])
   end

   if currentCell.row <@cells.size-1
     markBlob(@cells[currentCell.row+1][currentCell.col])
   end

   if currentCell.col>0
     markBlob(@cells[currentCell.row][currentCell.col-1])
   end

   if currentCell.col<@cells.size-1
     markBlob(@cells[currentCell.row][currentCell.col+1])
   end

 end

 def countblobs
   count = 0
   for i in 0..10
     for j in 0..10
       cell = @cells[i][j]
       if !cell.visited && cell.data.nil?
         count++
         markBlob(cell)
       end
     end
   end
   return count
 end

 def to_s
   for i in 0..10
     for j in 0..10
       if @cells[i][j].data.nil?
         puts '- '
       else
       puts @cells[i][j].data + ' '
         end
     end
     puts "\n"
   end

 end

 blob = Blobs.new
 number = blob
 puts number

  end
```

this is the error i am getting:

```
C:\Ruby22\bin\ruby.exe -e         $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)         C:/Users/Nechama/RubymineProjects/blobs/blobs.rb
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:38:in   `require': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
    from C:/Users/Nechama/RubymineProjects/blobs/blobs.rb:3:in `<class:Blobs>'
    from C:/Users/Nechama/RubymineProjects/blobs/blobs.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `require ./Cell` -- you should `require` filepaths. It's not a filepath or even a string that could represent it..

Comment: by the error, you can see that the problem is in you blobs file, on line 3: `from C:/Users/Nechama/RubymineProjects/blobs/blobs.rb:3:in <class:Blobs>'`

Comment: how do i make it into a filepath?

Comment: that part seems to be working now. however it is not happy about the countblobs method. do you know what would be the problem over there?

Answer (score 0):

`require` should get *string* as an argument.

Use [require_relative](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/require_relative) to cell file

```
require_relative 'cell'
```

and put it above `class Blobs.`

More about [Including Other Files In Ruby](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/including_other_files_in_ruby.html)

Comment: /blobs/blobs.rb:62:in `each'
 /blobs/blobs.rb:62:in `block in to_s'
 /blobs/blobs.rb:61:in `each'
 blobs/blobs.rb:61:in `to_s'
        /blobs/blobs.rb:76:in `puts'
 blobs/blobs.rb:76:in `puts'
 /blobs/blobs.rb:76:in `<class:Blobs>'
 /blobs/blobs.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
 from -e:1:in `load'
 from -e:1:in `<main>'

Comment: That is another problem. You didn't assign cells in blob(separate) so `@cells[i][j]` doesn't have `data`. And move `blob = Blobs.new
  number = blob
  puts number` outside the class

Comment: i fixed that. and im now getting the following error in the else statement for blob(separate)

Comment: in `block (2 levels) in separate': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: You cannot assign instance variable outside instance method. put `@cells = Array.new(10){Array.new(10)}` inside `separate` or in `initialize` method

Comment: i tried both ways and im still getting the same error

Comment: You created array with length of 10 and tried to get the item in 11(array starts from 0). make your array to 11: `@cells = Array.new(11){Array.new(11)}`, or use `0...10` in each range.